# UniObjects for Java: How to get response String when error occurred in UniCommand.exec()

Tags: java, unidata, universe, uniobjects

I would like to be able to determine the exact reason that a `UniCommand` could not complete using UniObjects for Java in order to tell the user. I have the following code that behaves as expected under ideal conditions, but if `command` is not a valid command, `uniCommand.response()` returns an empty `String`. I would like to know exactly why the command could not execute. I tried to use`uniCommand.getSystemReturnCode()`, but it always returns `-1` if the command did not complete successfully and that's not enough information. How do I find out exactly what went wrong?

```
UniCommand uniCommand = uniSession.command();
uniCommand.setCommand(command);
uniCommand.exec();
int status = uniCommand.status();
//int sysRet = uniCommand.getSystemReturnCode();

if (status == UniObjectsTokens.UVS_COMPLETE) {
    output(uniCommand.response());
}
```

An Example:
When I execute `BLAH` via telnet on the UniVerse server itself I get:

```
Verb "BLAH" is not in your VOC.
```

and when I execute `LIST BLAH` I get:

```
RetrieVe: syntax error.  Unexpected sentence without filename.  Token was "".
          Scanned command was LIST 'BLAH'
```

I would like to get those exact error messages in my program using UniObjects for Java. Is that possible?

Comment: Your code seems like it should be returning the error message response. The response is retrieved when the command succeeds (EX: LIST <actual filename in your database>)? Or is that also returning a blank string?

Comment: I agree, it seems like it should be returning the error message. When the commands is successful, it returns the DB response as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem, and it does seem like a limitation of the uniobjects library.  One way to handle it is to wrap the command in a subroutine.

```
SUBROUTINE RUN.COMMAND(COMMAND,RESPONSE)
    EXECUTE COMMAND CAPTURING RESPONSE
END
```

Then use a UniSubroutine object to call it.

```
String command = "LIST BLAH";
UniSubroutine sub = uniSession.subroutine("RUN.COMMAND", 2);
sub.setArg(0, command);
sub.call();
UniDynArray response = new UniDynArray(sub.getArg(1));

for (int i = 0; i < response.dcount(); i++) {
    String line = response.extract(i).toString();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```