# Create Subroutine in Universe

Tags: universe

I have problems in identifying the error of UniObject during execute UniCommands. I saw the answer in [UniObjects for Java: How to get response String when error occurred in UniCommand.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146112/uniobjects-for-java-how-to-get-response-string-when-error-occurred-in-unicomman/32617588#32617588)

But I don't know how to create subroutine in Universe?

I saw this method CreateUniSubroutine but it only has name and # of parameters.

UniSubroutine sub = us1.CreateUniSubroutine("RUN.COMMAND", 2);

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In UniVerse you can use a subroutine inside and outside the program.
Let me show you how you can make a simple example.

Primary File:

```
0001 *EXAMPLE SUBROUTINE
0002       CRT 'ENTER A NUMBER OR Q TO QUIT:'
0003       INPUT NUM
0004       BEGIN CASE
0005          CASE NUM = "Q"
0006             GOSUB ENDPRG
0007          CASE NUM > 0
0008             CALL ADD5(NUM)
0009       END CASE
0010 ENDPRG:
0011       CRT 'END OF PROGRAM'
0012       CRT
0013    END
```

Subroutine file:

```
0001       SUBROUTINE ADD5(NUMBER)
0002       NUMBER+=5
0003       CRT NUMBER
0004       RETURN
0005    END
```

In the primary file on the line 6 and 8 you can see the subroutines.
I hope to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I generally only do Universe from inside native Universe, but what it looks like here is that the command "CreateUniSubroutine" creates a reflection of a Universe subroutine, not a subroutine itself.

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but this appears to allow you to leverage existing Universe code and not add new logic.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Subroutine in Universe.

1. You need to have a subroutine source file folder in your UniVerse account with file type 19. It can be local or qpoint from other UniVerse account.
2. Use any text editor (like notepad) to edit your subroutine source code and save into the source folder above.
3. TELNET to your UniVerse account and type the following to basic the subroutine.

   BASIC source.folder subroutine.name

Example: If the source folder name is SOURCE and Subroutine file name is RUN.COMMAND. the command will be

```
BASIC SOURCE RUN.COMMAND
```

4. You may need to CATALOG the subroutine in your data account before it can call from UniObject.